# Plotly -Ignoring the weekend dates in a statistical graph

Tags: plotly

For a selected time range of 1 week, the modified code will display only weekday dates on the x-axis, excluding weekend dates. This ensures that only relevant trading days are shown, providing a clearer visualization of the stock data.

This is the Impact i want but I am not getting it

and mind u i dont have any weekend dates in my database.

Plss help me if possible gimme the modified code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Stocks</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css">
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .container {
            padding: 20px;
        }

        #graph {
            width: 100%;
            height: 70vh;
            /* Adjust the height percentage as per your preference */
            overflow: auto;
            /* Add overflow property for scrolling on small screens */
        }

        #graph .plot-container .plotly .modebar {
            display: none;
        }

        #graph::-webkit-scrollbar {
            display: none;
            /* Hide scrollbar on Chrome, Safari, and Opera */
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Select Stock</h1>
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="stockSelect">Stocks:</label>
                <select class="form-control select2" id="stockSelect">
                    {% for symbol in symbols|sort %}
                    <option>{{ symbol }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="timeRangeSelect">Time Range:</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="timeRangeSelect">
                    <option value="1D">1 Day</option>
                    <option value="1W">1 Week</option>
                    <option value="1M">1 Month</option>
                    <option value="1Y">1 Year</option>
                    <option value="All">Whole Data</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="generateBtn">Generate Graph</button>
        </form>
        <div id="graph" class="mt-4"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.select2').select2();

            function generateGraph(selectedSymbol, selectedTimeRange) {
                $('#graph').empty();
                var url;
                if (selectedTimeRange === 'All') {
                    url = '/stock_data/' + selectedSymbol + '/All';
                } else {
                    url = '/' + selectedSymbol + '/' + selectedTimeRange;
                }
                $.get(url, function (data) {
                    var dates = data.map(function (row) {
                        var date = new Date(row.date);
                        if (selectedTimeRange !== '1D' || selectedTimeRange == '1D') {
                            date.setUTCHours(date.getUTCHours() - 5); // Subtract 5 hours for the desired time adjustment
                            date.setUTCMinutes(date.getUTCMinutes() - 30); // Subtract 30 minutes for the desired time adjustment
                        }
                        return date;
                    });

                    var adjClose = data.map(function (row) {
                        return row.adj_close;
                    });

                    if (selectedTimeRange === '1W' || selectedTimeRange === '1M' || selectedTimeRange === '1Y') {
                        // Select only the latest adj_close for each day
                        var filteredDates = [];
                        var filteredAdjClose = [];
                        var uniqueDates = [];

                        for (var i = dates.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                            var currentDate = dates[i].toLocaleDateString('en-US');
                            if (!uniqueDates.includes(currentDate)) {
                                uniqueDates.push(currentDate);
                                filteredDates.unshift(dates[i]);
                                filteredAdjClose.unshift(adjClose[i]);
                            }
                        }

                        dates = filteredDates;
                        adjClose = filteredAdjClose;

                        // Generate tick values using the filtered dates
                        var tickData = filteredDates.map(function (date) {
                            return date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', { timeZone: 'GMT' });
                        });
                    } else {
                        // Generate tick values for other time ranges
                        var tickData = dates.map(function (date) {
                            return date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', { timeZone: 'GMT' });
                        });
                    }

                    var trace = {
                        x: dates,
                        y: adjClose,
                        type: 'scatter',
                        mode: 'lines',
                        name: selectedSymbol,
                        line: {
                            color: 'lightblue' // Set the line color to light blue
                        }
                    };

                    var layout = {
                        xaxis: {
                            type: 'date',
                            ticktext: tickData,
                            tickfont: {
                                size: 8, // Adjust the tick label size as per your preference
                                color: 'white',
                                weight: 'bold'
                            }
                        },
                        yaxis: {
                            title: '',
                            tickfont: {
                                color: 'white',
                                weight: 'bold' // Set the tick label color to white and bold
                            }
                        },
                        autosize: true, // Enable automatic resizing of the graph
                        margin: {
                            l: 40,
                            r: 10,
                            t: 50,
                            b: 40
                        },
                        // Disable zoom and pan interactions
                        hovermode: false,
                        dragmode: false,
                        selectdirection: 'h',
                        showZoom: false,
                        showPan: false,
                        displayModeBar: false,
                        plot_bgcolor: 'black', // Set the graph background color to black
                        paper_bgcolor: 'black' // Set the plot area background color to black
                    };

                    var data = [trace];

                    Plotly.newPlot('graph', data, layout);
                });
            }

            $('#generateBtn').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var selectedSymbol = $('#stockSelect').val();
                var selectedTimeRange = $('#timeRangeSelect').val();
                generateGraph(selectedSymbol, selectedTimeRange);
            });
        });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```